# TagHelper in ASP.NET Core doesn't update values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, tag-helpers

[image]

When I click on the link save Order I want the site to be redirected to
`.../saveOrders?trans=[selected value]&quant=[selected value]`
instead the site always redirects to `.../saveOrders?quant=`
no matter which values I type in for the parameters.

I am using MVC and TagHelpers:

Here is a snippet of the view for the picture:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <form asp-action="CreateOrder">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="TransactionType"class="control-label">Transaction Type</label>
            <select asp-for="TransactionType" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select Transaction Type</option>
                <option value="B">BUY</option>
                <option value="BD">BUY DURCHLIEFERUNG/UMLEGUNG</option>
                <option value="S">SELL</option>
                <option value="SD">SELL DURCHLIEFERUNG/UMLEGUNG</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="TransactionType" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
@*Eingabe*@
<div class="col-md-3">
    <form asp-action="CreateOrder">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Quantity" class="control-label">Quantity</label>
            <input asp-for="Quantity" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

```
<div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="history.go(-1);">Back to List</a>
<a asp-controller="Order" asp-action="saveOrders" asp-route-transaction="@Model.TransactionType" asp-route-quant="@Model.Quantity" >Save Order</a>
```

Here is my model:

```
public class CreateOrderModel
{
    public CreateOrderResponse1 CreateOrderResponse1 { get; set; }
    public SaveOrderResponse1 SaveOrderResponse1 { get; set; }
    public bool Save { get; set; }
    public long InstrumentId { get; set; }
    public string instName { get; set; }
    public string securCode { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public long Exchange { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime quoteDate { get; set; }
    public double nominal { get;set; }
    public long code { get; set; }
    public string pName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string TransactionType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double Quantity { get; set; }

    public string strategyCode { get; set; }

    
    
    public string LastAction { get; set; }
   
    
  
    public string comment { get; set; }
```

and here is the Controller saveOrders which I am trying to call through the click on saveOrder.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> saveOrders(string transaction, double quant)
    {
        saveOrder.TransactionType = transaction;
        saveOrder.Quantity = quant;
        saveOrder.Save = true;
        await saveOrder.OnCreateOrder();
        return View(saveOrder);
    }
```

When I call the Controller function `SaveOrders` from the view the parameters `null` and `0` are passed for transaction and quant, no matter what I select.

Comment: I allready tried selectTagHelpers but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use two forms, but every form do not have the button of submmit. You can try to add javascript to edit the url of **Save Order**.

Here is an exmple. When click **Save Order** , edit its href.

```
<a onclick="save()" id="saveorder" asp-controller="Order" asp-action="saveOrders" asp-route-transaction="@Model.TransactionType" asp-route-quant="@Model.Quantity">Save Order</a>

@section Scripts{ 
<script>
    function save() {
        var transaction = document.getElementById('TransactionType').value
        var quant = document.getElementById('Quantity').value
        console.log(transaction, quant)
        document.getElementById('saveorder').href = '/Order/saveOrders?transaction=' + transaction + '&quant=' + quant
    }
</script>
}
```

Then I select *BUY*.

[image]

Get it in this action.

[image]